# How to create mobile version of Desktop site in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, mobile

Basically I have a website `http://stylanzo.com` which is responsive but on mobile i want to change that view.....basically on mobile i want to url like this `m.stylanzo.com`.

I don't want to change in my current theme....is it possible to run my site according to device.. like if user open on mobile then it will show m.stylanzo.com and desktop stylanzo.com.

And also I want to do this on my current site without any new installation. 
I hear about multiple store ..but don't know how to do this.

Comment: Create an other store for your mobile device and mobile friendly theme if you don't have already.

Comment: Maybe you can create a new store view and use a mobile theme for mobile device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento has a functionality to configure which templates, layout, css and js to use for device.

You even do not need to change url.

Go to **System -> Configuration -> Design -> Themes**

Add exceptions for **Templates, Skin (Images / CSS), Layout**.

Exception has two fields:

**Matched Expression** - possible values are "iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini|Fennec"

**Value** - name of the theme in your package.

Lets assume that we set Value to "mobile" then your folder structure should look like this:

```
app/design/frontend/your_packege_name/mobile/layout/ 
app/design/frontend/your_packege_name/mobile/template/ 
skin/frontend/your_packege_name/mobile/css/
skin/frontend/your_packege_name/mobile/js/
skin/frontend/your_packege_name/mobile/images/
```

If you want different look on different devices add more exceptions.