# How to make http://m.example.com and make theme mobile version in my magento store?

Tags: magento-1.9, mobile

How to make http://m.example.com and make theme mobile version in my magento store ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is functionality in Magento with which you can configure different templates, layout, css and js file for mobile.

You can find the [Answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/62141/45103) here. Which is almost similar to you.